# You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

How can I solve this error?

My entity class names

1. Management
2. Information
3. Address

There are all entity class have one to one mapping

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT mg FROM Management AS mg INNER JOIN Information AS info ON info.id = mg.id INNER JOIN Address AS add  ON info.id = add.id WHERE ad.divition =:divition and ad.district =:district and ad.thana =:thana and ad.postOffice =:postOffice", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: You are using the alias add for Address, but the where condition use ad instead of add

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.